# Open new window with pdf with node-webkit

Tags: node.js, pdf, nw.js

I have a website and i have some users that i have to install to them a node-webkit installation to view the websote.

I just have a package.json with main pointed to my url.

This is my code:

```
    {
  "name": "nw-demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "http://dev.its-my-website.com",
  "window":{
    "toolbar": false,
    "frame": true,
    "width": 800,
    "height": 500,
    "position": "mouse",
    "min_width": 400,
    "min_height": 200


  }
}
```

All its right, but i have a problem, because in my website i have a link that open a new tab and display a pdf file. 
The code is :

```
window.open('xxxxxx')
```

When i launch with nw start , This link don't open a new window just launch a download of the file.

Thanks Everybody for your Help

Comment: window.open("x") just tells the browser to open that link. On desktop browsers, usually that link is displayed in the browser. On most android devices, it is downloaded. On IPads, it is also displayed in the browser. There is no way to display a pdf in your browser if the browser doesn't support it.

Comment: webkit not support pdf browsing?

Comment: Which version of NWJS? can you provide sample app to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you blocking popups by any chance with something like...

```
win.on('new-win-policy',function(frame,url,policy){policy.ignore();}
```

Without this policy, PDFs open in new windows just fine at my end.

I hope you're not using an old version of NW that didn't support PDFs!